# Why is CAP_NET_ADMIN insufficient permissions for ioctl(TUNSETIFF)?

Tags: linux, capabilities, tap, ioctl

I'm trying to write a tun/tap program in Rust. Since I don't want it to run as root I've added CAP_NET_ADMIN to the binary's capabilities:

```
$sudo setcap cap_net_admin=eip target/release/tunnel
$getcap target/release/tunnel
target/release/tunnel = cap_net_admin+eip
```

However, this is not working. Everything I've read says that this is the only capability required to create tuns, but the program gets an EPERM on the ioctl. In strace, I see this error:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
ioctl(3, TUNSETIFF, 0x7ffcdac7c7c0)     = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I've verified that the binary runs successfully with full root permissions, but I don't want this to require sudo to run. Why is CAP_NET_ADMIN not sufficient here?

For reference, I'm on `Linux version 4.15.0-45` there are only a few ways I see that this ioctl can return EPERM in the kernel (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/drivers/net/tun.c#L2194) and at least one of them seems to be satisfied. I'm not sure how to probe the others:

```
if (!capable(CAP_NET_ADMIN))
    return -EPERM;
...
if (tun_not_capable(tun))
    return -EPERM;
...
if (!ns_capable(net->user_ns, CAP_NET_ADMIN))
    return -EPERM;
```

Comment: if [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506774/308316)'s not it, please complete your question with the exact parameters you're passing to `ioctl(TUNSETIFF)` via the `ifreq` struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same issue when writing a Rust program that spawns a `tunctl` process for creating and managing TUN/TAP interfaces.

For instance:

```rust
let tunctl_status = Command::new("tunctl")
            .args(&["-u", "user", "-t", "tap0"])
            .stdout(Stdio::null())
            .status()?;
```

failed with:

```
$ ./target/debug/nio
TUNSETIFF: Operation not permitted
tunctl failed to create tap network device.
```

even though the `NET_ADMIN` file capability was set:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin=+ep ./target/debug/nio
$ getcap ./target/debug/nio                       
./target/debug/nio cap_net_admin=ep
```

The manual states:

> Because  inheritable  capabilities  are not generally preserved across execve(2) when running as a non-root user, applications that wish to run helper programs with elevated capabilities should consider using ambient capabilities, described below.

To cover the case of `execve()` system calls, I used ambient capabilities.

> **Ambient (since Linux 4.3)** This is a set of capabilities that are preserved across an execve(2) of a program that is not privileged.  The ambient capability set obeys the invariant that no capability can ever be ambient if it is not both permitted and inheritable.

**Example solution:** For convenience, I use the [`caps-rs`](https://github.com/lucab/caps-rs) library.

```rust
// Check if `NET_ADMIN` is in permitted set.
let perm_net_admin = caps::has_cap(None, CapSet::Permitted, Capability::CAP_NET_ADMIN);
match perm_net_admin {
    Ok(is_in_perm) => {
        if !is_in_perm {
            eprintln!("Error: The capability 'NET_ADMIN' is not in the permitted set!");
            std::process::exit(1)
        }
    }
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("Error: {:?}", e);
        std::process::exit(1)
    }
}


// Note: The ambient capability set obeys the invariant that no capability can ever be ambient if it is not both permitted and inheritable.
caps::raise(
    None,
    caps::CapSet::Inheritable,
    caps::Capability::CAP_NET_ADMIN,
)
.unwrap_or_else(fail_due_to_caps_err);

caps::raise(None, caps::CapSet::Ambient, caps::Capability::CAP_NET_ADMIN)
    .unwrap_or_else(fail_due_to_caps_err);
```

Finally, setting the `NET_ADMIN` file capability suffices:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin=+ep ./target/debug/nio
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess that the filesystem your `target/release/tunnel` binary resides on is mounted with the `nosuid` option. That will also affect file capabilities, not just the setuid bit.

Also, you won't be able to strace a set-capabilities or setuid binary as you do -- the kernel will ignore the file capabilities when calling `execve()` from a `ptrace`d process:

```
$ getcap tapy
tapy = cap_net_admin+eip
$ ./tapy
tapy: {tap1}
^C
$ strace -e trace=ioctl ./tapy
ioctl(3, TUNSETIFF, 0x7ffdc5b2fef0)     = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
tapy: ioctl TUNSETIFF: Operation not permitted
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 0):

While `CAP_NET_ADMIN` gives you permission to modify network configurations such as `iptables`, interfaces etc. for actual tapping and net i/o read you'll have to add the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability in addition to `CAP_NET_ADMIN`.

Together, they will grant you the ability you are seeking.